# Edit email content with a plugin on a quick campaign

Tags: email, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I'm having trouble to achieve this. What I would like to do is be able to edit the content (description) of an email entity for a qucik campaign before it's sent (or after it's created).

I've tried many different plugins registration without much luck.

Prevalidate Create Email : this one fires ok but only when a user creates and save the email. when the email is created by the quick campaign it is not triggered.

Prevalidate Send Email : this one fires only for when a single email is sent by a user action and does not allow to modify the description anywa

Prevalidate BackgroundSend Email: this one is correctly triggered when the emails created by a quick campaign are sent, but it does not let me modify the description.

Anyone has done that before ?

I'm using CRM 2011 online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution which is to simply use the plugin on Create Email Pre-Operation instead of Pre-Validation like I was doing.

For some reasons, the Pre-Validation doesn't trigger when emails are created in the background.

Comment: Thanks Etienne! You saved my day. Had it all set up and working on SEND message but when tried to send email from campaign for some ODD reason it doesn't work.